# Erro na função write do stringstream do c++

Tags: c++

Caros,

estou fazendo uma função para conversão de decimal para binário, que é retornado numa string. Como o C++ não tem `StringBuffer`, estou usando o `stringstream`. Contudo, sempre tenho erro de compilação ao usar a função `write` do `stringstream`. O código é este:

```
string toBin(int valor, int bits) {
    int resto = -1, i = 0;
    stringstream ss;

    if (valor == 0) {
        return "0";
    }

    while (valor > 0) {
        resto = valor % 2;
        valor = valor / 2;
        ss.seekp(0);
        ss.write(resto, i++);
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

A intenção é que a cada resto encontrado, eu o insira na primeira posição do stringstream, para formar o binário. E o erro encontrado é:

"invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Como poderia resolver esse problema? Ou existe alguma biblioteca do C++ que já faça a conversão de decimal para binário?

Grato!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como poderia resolver esse problema?

A função `write` aceita como parâmetro um `const char*` e você está tentando passar um número inteiro. Bem, os problemas de compilação seriam resolvidos se você convertesse o inteiro `resto` para um `const char*` com algo do tipo:

```
ss.write(std::to_string(resto).c_str(), i++);
```

Mas me parece que mesmo com essa conversão, o seu programa ainda não faria o que você espera dele e precisaria corrigir mais coisas.

> Ou existe alguma biblioteca do C++ que já faça a conversão de decimal para binário?

Sim, existe uma biblioteca que faz essa conversão. Você pode usar a classe  `std::bitset`. O construtor dela recebe o inteiro que você deseja converter para binário. E para converter de binário para `std::string` você poderia usar a função `to_string`. A sua função ficaria assim:

```
#include <bitset>


std::string toBin(int valor){
    return std::bitset<32>(valor).to_string();
}
```

Detalhe: a literal `32` representa o número de bits manipulados pela `std::bitset`, você pode alterar esse valor de acordo com a sua necessidade, mas esse valor precisa ser conhecido em tempo de compilação.

Comment: Perfeita resposta! Com o bitset não vou precisar tratar a quantidade de bits do retorno. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Esse código está desnecessariamente complicado.
Abaixo uma solução bem simples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static string toBin(int valor)
{
  // quantidade de bits num int
  int nBits = sizeof(int) * 8;

  // string que vai conter o valor em binario
  string result;

  for (int i = 0; i < nBits; i++)
  {
    // testa o ultimo bit 'a direita se e' 1 ou 0
    if (valor & 1)
      result.insert(0, 1, '1'); // insere '1' no inicio da string
    else
      result.insert(0, 1, '0'); // insere '0' no inicio da string

    // desloca o valor 1 bit 'a direita
    valor >>= 1; // valor = valor >> 1;
  }

  return result;
}

int main()
{
  cout << "*\n";
  cout << "* 10="  << toBin(10)  << "\n";
  cout << "* 16="  << toBin(16)  << "\n";
  cout << "* 255=" << toBin(255) << "\n";
  cout << "*\n";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Acabei utilizando a solução que o v.Santos sugeriu, por ser uma funcionalidade nativa do C++. De toda forma, essa sua solução é bem interessante também. Obrigado!